# Obtain GUID in search rest API in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Currently I am using SharePoint REST API, I am able to get GUID for each document. But for searching API, it doesn't return me GUID. Is there any way to get the GUID of the document?

```
https://<sharepoint-web-url>/_api/search/query
```